# How use return between methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, return

In my Program I have a button click, from that onclick event I am calling one method for some textbox validation. The code is:

```
  protected void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     CheckValidation();
    //Some other Code
  }

  public void CheckValidation()
  {
    if (txtphysi.Text.Trim() == "")
    {
       lblerrmsg.Visible = true;
       lblerrmsg.Text = "Please Enter Physician Name";
       return;
    }
    //Some other Code
  }
```

Here if `txtphysi.text` is null then it comes into loop and use return then it came from the  `CheckValidation()` method only and it continues in `btnupdate_Click` event, but here I want to stop the execution process in `btnupdate_Click` also. How can I do it?

Comment: Consider that "" is String.Empty and is differnet from null

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is very simple programming logic in my understanding that you need to apply here..

That is return `Boolean` from `CheckValidation()` method instead of return `void` so that parent function knows the state from the function's execution.

```
protected void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var flag = CheckValidation();
    if(!flag)
        return;
    //Some other Code
}

public bool CheckValidation()
{
    var flag = false; // by default flag is false
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtphysi.Text)) // Use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() method instead of Trim() == "" to comply with framework rules
    {
       lblerrmsg.Visible = true;
       lblerrmsg.Text = "Please Enter Physician Name";
       return flag;
    }
    //Some other Code
    flag = true; // change the flag to true to continue execution
    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this:

1) Change the return type of the `CheckValidation()` method to bool. In your `btnupdate_Click()` method do something along the lines of

```
if(!CheckValidation())
{
    return;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: And what's the other way?

Comment: The other way would be to throw an exception in the validation method and catch it inside of Click method. But that would be the ugly way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

If this is ASP.NET, which you have tagged it as, then you should perhapts use a RequiredFieldValidator (for webforms), and you could use DataAnnotations if you are using MVC: http://forums.asp.net/t/1983198.aspx?RequiredFieldValidator+in+MVC

Answer (score 2):

Though answer has been already accepted, but I believe this is not good practice to put code in events. Better to use delegates for such purposes.

```
public class Sample
{
    public Sample()
    {
        UpdateAction = OnUpdate;
    }

    Action UpdateAction = null;

    private void OnUpdate()
    {
        //some update related stuff
    }


    protected void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckValidation(UpdateAction);
    }

    public void CheckValidation(Action action)
    {
        if (txtphysi.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            lblerrmsg.Visible = true;
            lblerrmsg.Text = "Please Enter Physician Name";
            return;
        }
        action();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

```
protected void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!CheckValidation())
    {
        //Some other Code
    }
}

public bool CheckValidation()
{
    if (string.isnullorEmpty(txtphysi.Text.Trim()) )
    {
        lblerrmsg.Visible = true;
        lblerrmsg.Text = "Please Enter Physician Name";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Some other Code
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Putting the other code after the `return` statements obviously isn't going to work.

Comment: `else
        {
          return true;
        }
        //Some other Code` means you have unreachable code.. :P